# Jenkins grunt task 'karma' not found

Tags: javascript, jenkins, gruntjs, karma-runner

I'm actively working to find a solution, but this is an interesting issue.  I have Jenkins installed on two RedHat VMs.  I am having trouble with a grunt task in the more recent VM, which I believe has a newer version of Jenkins.

I check out everything with SVN first; that works fine.  Then I install the node and bower dependencies.  Next I run a couple of Grunt tasks and then do some stuff after the Maven build.  The problem lies within the Grunt "test" task.

**Execute shell** step

```
cd /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/app-grunt-maven/app
npm install
bower install
grunt --force lint
grunt test
grunt build
```

The error reads `Task "karma" not found. Use --force to continue.`

I have Grunt, Bower, Karma, and Git installed globally.  `npm install` takes care of all the JS dependencies, including `grunt-karma` and `phantomjs`.

This is how the karma task is defined in my Gruntfile.  Also note that this job is working on a different VM. Do I need to install some other global dependencies?

```
karma: {
        unit: {
            configFile: 'src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the `node_modules` folder and running the Jenkins job again.  The command I used was `npm install`.  I may have used `echo 'password' | sudo -S npm install` at some point, but I don't think that would've messed things up.  Perhaps the problem was that I didn't install my global dependencies first, which could have caused npm to install some of the modules improperly.